# Adding Facebook register/login to app

Tags: ios, facebook

So I've done some research to add a register and login feature to my new app. I want to add the following things: Facebook, Twitter and my own register/login options for the users.

I've dived into some SSO from Facebook, looked into some php scripts on how they do it. So basically correct me if İ'm wrong.

- User clicks on Facebook button
- App checks if user is already in the database with the `oath_provide` en `oauth_uid`

  - If not: User is getting asked by Facebook API for accepting
  - App submits the `oauth_provide` (Facebook) and `oauth_uid` (user id) from the media that they've chosen to my SQL database.
  - User accepts and logs in to my app.
- User is logged in

Same is probably for Twitter. Thanks in advance!